# How to post script at blogger, create script view at template

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

Someone know how to create script view at blogger.com?
i need to post script like this picture at my blog

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean add a script too your blog? It can be done with it

**With gadget**

choose 'Tata Letak' menu on left, and on your page view find 'Tambah Gadget' and choose 'HTML/Javascript' then add your script.

**Edit whole page**

Or you can edit your whole page, choose 'Template' menu on left and click 'edit HTML' button, then add your script.

Then you can add a **syntax highlighter**, depending on this article

> http://www.bungfrangki.com/2015/07/membuat-syntax-highlighter-otomatis-di-blogger.html
>   http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2015/04/SyntaxHighlighter-Shortcode-for-Blogspot.html

Comment: Bukan mas bro, ane mau bikin postingan tentang coding, jadi maksudnya biar bagian code nya gak sama dengan body yang lain. Atau kayak kita mau copy script di stackoverflow ini, script nya dipisahin dari body..

Comment: Itu bisa dicoba syntax highliter, bisa googling juga

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should have `code` option but If it doesn't When you are going to add new post there's an option to see the HTML codes in your post Go there and put your codes in `<code>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

To display codes in blogger posts, from your editor press **Quote** button and insert your code. this will put your code between `<blockquote> </blockquote>`
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88HBa.png)

and you can style the `<blockquote>` with CSS.